# java error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, null, addition

i wrote this method that will add a object to the array 
but it get me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

i check all the variables and i think there is nothing null :((

this is my add method

```
    }
}
```

the error is in the add_b() method

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Kindergarten.add_b(Kindergarten.java:39)
    at ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:22)
```

Comment: paste the stacktrace.

Comment: You need to (1) show us all of the code, not just the parts where _you_ think  the problem might be (2) tell us which line is actually mentioned in the stack trace, so we don't have to guess.  Without those things, nobody can help you.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm really sorry this is the first time for me asking here , i edit it , can you help me please? :(

Comment: "Add a BABY" ? What program is this ? :-D @user3347862 Make an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: @LittleChild a Kindergarten program XD

Comment: @user3347862 Glad to hear that ! I thought something else. Please forgive me. I have a dirty mind.

Comment: you should think about structuring your code better

Comment: after reformatting your code a little bit, I have to agree with @donfuxx, single line methods like (getSomething{return this.something;} are ok, if you like them. But you should avoid `}` at the end of a line – put them in a new line instead to keep your code clean and avoid errors

Comment: @GameDroids thank you for the advice i will notice about this next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in Kindergarten constructor, instead of initializing arr, you are creating local variable, it should look like this:

```
public Kindergarten(String name, int numOfbaby) {
    this.name = name;
    arr = new BABY[numOfbaby];
    currnt = 0;
}
```

secondly, you have an ininite loop, move instruction and reading of input into loop.

another issue is that you have invalid format parameters, just use plain concatenation

last, but not least you are missing `System.out.println` in `display_all` method.

loop should start like this:

```
Kindergarten k = new Kindergarten("baby", 10);

while (true) {
    System.out
            .println("what do you want to do? \n a-add a baby. \n b-search for a baby \n c-Delet a baby. \n d-Display all babys.\n e-how many babys need inoculation \n f-exit");
    char f = read.next().charAt(0);
//(...)
}
```

Comment: Another problem is that in main, the `BABY` is created with `null` age, and then in `Kindergarten.add_b(BABY)`, the copy-constructor is used, which tries to retrieve the age from the baby.

Comment: @gla3dr actually, the age is not `null`, just `0` but I guess this should be covered in creation process as well.

Comment: @endriu_l please can you clarification "move instruction and reading of input into loop." iam not good in english sorry < and yes now i have infinite loop . you mean i remove while loop?

Comment: @gla3dr thank you :D i do the age with set method and it works ! but i have infinite loop XD

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initialization of  `arr` happens only in the second Kindergarten constructor. 
In the first Kindergarten constructor, `arr` is a local variable.
`BABY arr[]=new BABY[numOfbaby];`

Also, methods like `setarr`, `setname`, `setcurrnt` are not being used. It will be good if you can clean them up if not used.

Comment: yes i know that i don't use it , but this is a homework and they asked us to do it , and thank you very much